# Jquery Tools Slideshow Plugin: How to override default configs

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

On this page: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/slideshow.html

Halfway down the page I find this code under the heading of Usage:

```
$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

 // enable "cross-fading" effect
 effect: 'fade',
 fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

 // start from the beginning after the last tab
 rotate: true

// use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
}).slideshow();
```

How can I modify (or rather, what is the proper syntax) the last line, where it says

```
.slideshow();
```

and change the interval to 6000 instead of the default interval:3000?

Comment: put in the extra parameter assignment between the fn brackets? `interval: 6000,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most jquery plugins, you provide configuration options like this.

```
.slideshow({interval: 6000});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here two params are being passed. the first is the your element `".images > div"` and the second one is a hash that represents configuration options. If you check the link you have provided, all configuration options are listed there along with their respsctive default value ie if you dont specify a custom value for an option, default value will be used. So to set a custom value to interval, add `interval : 6000` below the line `rotate: true` . I think that should do what you want.

Comment: I tried that, but couldn't get it to work.  Thanks for your help.